# create "dynamic query" in nodejs with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I was wondering if it was possible to make a "dynamic condition" with sequelize using findOne/findOrCreate etc instead of row SQL query

i use it with graphQL and arguments could be optionnal in graphQL, so what i want to do is :

if i have id and name as argument :

```
user.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        id: args.id,
        name : args.name,  
      }
    })
```

and if i have id, name and email :

```
user.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        id: args.id,
        name : args.name, 
        email: args.email,
      }
    })
```

so it is possible to have a parameter inside the findOrCreate to check if something exist(here, args.email) and if not, doesn't include it inside the query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the the function and import that function:

```
export const findOrCreate = async function (query) {
    try {
        const user = await user.findOrCreate(query);
        return user;
    } catch (e) {
        throw Error('Error occur while finding or creating the records’);
    }
};
```

wherever you need import that function and call with the required parameters

```
const query = {
    where: { // we search for this user
        id: args.id,
        name : args.name, 
        email: args.email,
    },
    defaults: {
        job: 'Technical Lead JavaScript'
    }  // if it doesn't exist, we create it with this additional data
}

await findOrCreate(query )
```